# Change variable value according to functions results

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

Hello everyone!

I created a tkinter interface where 3 buttons are launching 3 differents functions once cliqued. Each of this functions is reatriving datas from differents locations (COM ports & Selenium/webdriver).

From this differents function, I would like to update variables that I intend to print later, however when I try to use "return" at the end of each function, this is not working.

Therefore, I assume my structure is wrong, but I don't see how, could you please help to understand the issue here?

```
import tkinter as tk

stack_lenght = 0
frequency_P = 0
frequency_S1 = 0
frequency_S2 = 0
stack_power = 0
amplitude1 = 0
amplitude2 = 0
amplitude3 = 0
amplitude4 = 0


def Get_lenght():
   #my code 
   return stack_lenght = lenght_measure

def Get_frequencies():
   #my code 
   return frequency_P = Frequency_measured

def Get_amplitudes():
   #my code 
   ....

# My Tkinter interface bellow
```

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to use `global`, because changes made inside a function are on local scope and wont take effect outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try :

```
def Get_lenght():
    #your code 
    global stack_lenght
    stack_lenght = lenght_measure
    return stack_lenght

#rest of code
```

For me, running python 3.8.3, throws error syntax when trying to assign value at return.

Defining value as `global stack_lenght` will keep the value set inside the `Get_lenght()` function.